# How to rotate the entire kivy application main window?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, raspberry-pi4

I have built a kivy application that is designed for use in a touchscreen device in portrait orientation. However the device itself (custom built) is only set up to run applications in landscape.

I need to rotate the entire application window 90° but when i use

`Window.rotation = 90`

all of my position hints get messed up as the actual width and height are swapped

When I use

```
canvas.before:
    PushMatrix
    Rotate:
        angle: 90
        origin: self.center
canvas.after:
    PopMatrix
```

the aspect ratio seems to be correct, but I end up with on_press inputs being rotated by 90° and not lining up with the buttons displayed (i.e. invisible buttons in the original correct locations, and visible buttons now in a new location due to rotated window.

Is there a module that I have not found that rotates the entire application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the config.ini file on raspberry pi.
it would be in the .kivy folder.
In the file you need to find the graphics section and under graphics section find the rotation and change to to 90, 180 or 270

```
[kivy]
keyboard_repeat_delay = 300
keyboard_repeat_rate = 30
log_dir = logs
log_enable = 1
log_level = info
log_name = kivy_%y-%m-%d_%_.txt
window_icon = 
keyboard_mode = 
keyboard_layout = qwerty
desktop = 1
exit_on_escape = 1
pause_on_minimize = 0
kivy_clock = default
default_font = ['Roboto', 'data/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf', 'data/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf', 'data/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf', 'data/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf']
log_maxfiles = 100
window_shape = data/images/defaultshape.png
config_version = 21

[graphics]
display = -1
fullscreen = 0
height = 600
left = 0
maxfps = 60
multisamples = 2
position = auto
**rotation = 0**
show_cursor = 1
top = 0
width = 800
resizable = 1
borderless = 0
window_state = visible
minimum_width = 0
minimum_height = 0
min_state_time = .035
allow_screensaver = 1
shaped = 0
vsync = 
verify_gl_main_thread = 1
custom_titlebar = 0
custom_titlebar_border = 5

[input]
mouse = mouse
wm_touch = wm_touch
wm_pen = wm_pen

[postproc]
double_tap_distance = 20
double_tap_time = 250
ignore = []
jitter_distance = 0
jitter_ignore_devices = mouse,mactouch,
retain_distance = 50
retain_time = 0
triple_tap_distance = 20
triple_tap_time = 375

[widgets]
scroll_timeout = 250
scroll_distance = 20
scroll_friction = 1.
scroll_stoptime = 300
scroll_moves = 5

[modules]

[network]
useragent = curl
```

but I have run into the problem of the touch not flipping correct and that needs to be changed in the pi.

Comment: Thanks @Dobbeltop - that worked! I ended up making a new file in the app directory called "app_settings.ini" and added `Config.read ('app_settings.ini')` to the main application